# How to add JS for modules in prestashop 1.5?

Tags: jquery, prestashop

Am developing a module in prestashop 1.5. Am using displayAdminProductsExtra hook to display tpl file in admin tab. when i include my jquery code in tpl, it works fine. but when i try to make it as new file and include its not working. so far I tried the below methods..

using displayBackOfficeHeader to register a hook and called like this..

```
public function hookdisplayBackOfficeHeader($params) 
{
    $this->context->controller->addJS(($this->_path).'abc.js');
}
```

and I tried to add it in displayAdminProductsExtra also like this..

```
$this->context->controller->addJS(_MODULE_DIR_.$this->module->name.'/views/js/abc.js'); //first tried..
$this->context->controller->addJS(($this->_path).'abc.js','all'); //second tried this..
```

And I tried with getcontent like this..

```
public function getContent()
{   
    $this->_html= '<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.min.js">
        <script src="../modules/abc/abc.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>';
    return $this->_html;
}
```

but these methods didn't add my js file. Dont know where am making mistake.any help would be appreciated.

Comment: [look at this for detailed answer](http://www.vipulhadiya.com/prestashop-module-development-tutorial-creating-front-and-admin-view-in-prestashop-module/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you are creating a Prestashop module, you must add the function hookHeader and within it, the line that adds the js in your page.

Would need something like this:

```
public function hookHeader ($ params)
{
     $ this-> controller-> addJS (($ this-> _path). 'abc.js');
}
```

On the other hand, looking at the code of the module blockcategories in blockcategories.php file we see the following:

```
public function displayForm()
{
...
}
```

This function is to create a page for module configuration, in the same way you use other modules. Maybe it's a simpler option, but faster to develop.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

**The hook `DisplayHeader` (or `Header`) is for registering assets in a front-office pages!**

This is right for your JavaScript path:

```
$this->context->controller->addJS($this->_path . 'abc.js');
```

But you didn't register jQuery assets by this method before registering your JavaScript:

```
$this->context->controller->addJquery();
```

Also, you should not use the hook `DisplayBackOfficeHeader`. Instead of it, you should use the hook `ActionAdminControllerSetMedia`.

**Here is the detailed information, [how to register JavaScript in a back-office (in admin pages)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53147760/1856214)**.