# Show my module JS at footer in prestashop

Tags: php, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I am developing a module in prestashop. I have a JS for configuration page for my module. I am using `displayBackOfficeHeader` hook to add my JS in header. But after installing my module when i configure my module it's give me `Jquery` issue because my JS in adding at top means before `jquery.js`

Que 1) How to manage that my JS should add in header after `Jquery.js`?

Que 2) If we can't manage same as que Ist then how to add JS in footer?

Comment: What do you use to add the js to that hook right now? "$this->context->controller->addJS(($this->_path).'myjavascript.js');" ?

Comment: yes the same 
 `$this->context->controller->addJS(($this->_path) .'views/js/presta_settings.js');`

Answer (score 4):

In most cases **to add any asset (JavaScript or CSS) to a back-office (admin pages)** you should use the hook `actionAdminControllerSetMedia()`.
Full steps to register correctly a JavaScript file are:

Step 1. Register the hook on a module install:

```
public function install()
{
    if (!parent::install()) {
        return false;
    }

    // After a module installation, register the hook
    if (!$this->registerHook('actionAdminControllerSetMedia')) {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Step 2. Then, add your JavaScript asset:

```
public function hookActionAdminControllerSetMedia()
{
    // Adds jQuery and some it's dependencies for PrestaShop
    $this->context->controller->addJquery();

    // Adds your's JavaScript from a module's directory
    $this->context->controller->addJS($this->_path . 'views/js/example.js');
}
```

**There are different ways and several methods that can be used to register assets in a back-office (admin pages)** (they are listed in the order of the execution):

1. The hook `hookDisplayBackOfficeHeader()`
2. The controller's method `AdminControllerCore::setMedia()`
3. The hook `actionAdminControllerSetMedia()`
4. A module's method `Module::getContent()`
5. The hook `hookDisplayBackOfficeFooter()`

**To add an inline code**, the best way is use the hook `hookDisplayBackOfficeFooter()`. For example:

```
public function hookDisplayBackOfficeFooter()
{
    return '
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var EXAMPLE_VARIABLE = "Hello, Zapalm!";
        </script>
    ';
}
```

**Yet another example for a case when you need to add a JavaScript asset but in a child class of AdminController of your module (for PrestaShop 1.7):**

```
public function setMedia($isNewTheme = false)
{
    parent::setMedia($isNewTheme);

    $this->addCSS(_MODULE_DIR_ . $this->module->name . '/views/css/example.css');
    $this->addJS(_MODULE_DIR_ . $this->module->name . '/views/js/example.js');
}
```

**For PrestaShop 1.6 and 1.5 you can do also like in this example but you need to remove `$isNewTheme` parameter from the method definition and the parent method call.**

**References:**

1. [Asset management in PrestaShop 1.7.](https://devdocs.prestashop.com/1.7/themes/getting-started/asset-management/)
2. [How to add an external asset to a front-office page in PrestaShop 1.7.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53148895/1856214)
3. [The explanation of which methods to use: addJS or registerJavascript.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58618839/1856214)

Comment: If i use $this -> context -> controller ->registerJavascript() in hookActionAdminControllerSetMedia(), then I get error "undefined method named "registerStylesheet" of class "AdminModulesController""

Comment: I have updated this answer and I have also answered to [your question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58618839/1856214).

Answer (score 1):

If you go to "Modules" > "Hook positions" in BO, you can order the load of the modules.