# addJS function not working for admin in prestashop

Tags: prestashop

I am trying to add javascript file in prestashop admin using `backOfficeHeader` hook using a module but nothing happened. My code is given below.

```
public function install()
{
    if (!parent::install()
        || !$this->registerHook('backOfficeHeader'))
        return false;

    return parent::install() && 
     $this->registerHook('backOfficeHeader');
}

 public function hookBackOfficeHeader() {
   $this->context->controller->addJS(_MODULE_DIR_.$this->module->name.'js/hs_custom.js');
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are using PS 1.5 or 1.6 you should use hook "actionAdminControllerSetMedia".

Your module installer should check which prestashop version is used and then register the needed hook.

```
 if (version_compare(substr(_PS_VERSION_, 0, 3), '1.5', '<'))
      $this->registerHook('BackOfficeHeader');
 else
      $this->registerHook('actionAdminControllerSetMedia');
```

Then you need to addJS on each hook in its version format:
PS>=1.5

```
 public function hookActionAdminControllerSetMedia($params) { 
     $this->context->controller->addJS($this->_path.'views/js/hs_custom.js');
 }
```

PS<=1.4

```
public function hookBackOfficeHeader($params) { 
    Tools::addJS($this->_path.'views/js/hs_custom.js');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

did u try to check addJS path? I think nothing more can be possible if other JS files working.
**Try to use $this->_path.**

```
$this->context->controller->addJS($this->_path.'views/js/hs_custom.js');
```

1) Output path and check if it is valid.
2) Reload page and check network. Page load your script or not?
3) Remember to reset module if u change something with hooks.
4) Check module hooks.

Answer (score 0):

**You did several mistakes.**
This is the invalid access to the property: `$this->module->name`. Must be `$this->name`. I.e., the correct code to generate a path to JavaScript file is:

```
_MODULE_DIR_ . $this->name . '/js/hs_custom.js'
```

Or like this (shorted):

```
$this->_path . 'js/hs_custom.js'
```

You are also did the double installation of the module and of the hook.
You can use the hook `BackOfficeHeader`, but the hook `ActionAdminControllerSetMedia` is preferred.

**So, the correct example to add a JS and a CSS files for a back-office (i.e. for AdminController) via a module class is:**

```
public function hookActionAdminControllerSetMedia($params)
{ 
    // Adds your's CSS file from a module's directory
    $this->context->controller->addCSS($this->_path . 'views/css/example.css'); 

    // Adds your's JavaScript file from a module's directory
    $this->context->controller->addJS($this->_path . 'views/js/example.js');
}
```

**Here is the detailed information, [how to register JavaScript in a back-office (in admin pages)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53147760/1856214)**.

Answer (score 0):

I also met this problem, there is no error and warning, all grammar is right. But cannot find my js File.
I found the reason finally. In my case there is nothing in JS file and system passes this file which has no content always.

Answer (score -1):

For me "this->_path" dosn't work. My solution is to use **$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']**

```
public function hookActionAdminControllerSetMedia($params)
{
    // add necessary javascript to products back office
    if($this->context->controller->controller_name == 'AdminProducts' && Tools::getValue('id_product'))
    {
        $this->context->controller->addJS($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/modules/apl/views/js/jquery.ui.touch-punch.min.js");
    }
}
```