# Make a hook to be executed only on "onClick" button

Tags: hook, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I have a Prestashop module, and I want to execute a hook (inserting a product) just when clicking on a button.
Here is what I'm doing right now :

In the module.php file I'm using this function :

```
public function hookActionProductAdd()
{
       //code to create a product
}
```

In the module.tpl file I'm creating a button, its onClick execute the hook :

```
<button onclick="createProduct()">Create product</button>
```

And at the end of the tpl file I add the script code :

```
<script>
function createProduct() {
    {hook h='ActionProductAdd'}
}
</script>
```

The problem is the hook is executed every page access/reload, and I want it to execute only when clicking on the button.

Comment: Instead of calling the hook, you should just call the method to create a product, which will call the hook for you.

Comment: @TheDrot : The method to create the product is on the hook function. The hook function is on the php file. The only way to call a function from php file to tpl file is using hook. No?

Comment: Well then you are doing it wrong because the hook is to be used to do some extra stuff **after** a product is created.

Comment: @TheDrot : How can I proceed then if I want to achieve that? Where can I call a php function from module.php to module.tpl?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A hook is only executed at runtime, when Prestashop generates the template files. Here you want to create an ajax function in your module.

Your module files will look like this :

```
- mymodule.php
- ajax/
    - my_module_ajax.php
- js/
    - my_module.js
- views/
    - templates/
        - front/
            - my_module_template.tpl
```

In file `mymodule.php` you've got:

```php
<?php

if (!defined('_PS_VERSION_'))
    exit;

class MyModule extends Module
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        [...]
    }

    public function install()
    {
        if (!parent::install() || !$this->registerHook('header'))
            return false;
        return true;
    }

    public function hookHeader($params)
    {
        $this->context->controller->addJS(($this->_path).'js/my_module.js');
    }

    public function _ajax_create_product($params)
    {
        [...]
        return $result;
    }
}
```

In file `my_module_ajax.php` you've got:

```php
<?php
require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/../../../config/config.inc.php');
require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/../../../init.php');
require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/../mymodule.php');

$context = Context::getContext();

// Instance of module class
$module = new MyModule();

switch (Tools::getValue('action'))
{
    case 'createProduct':
        echo $module->_ajax_create_product(Tools::getValue('test'));
        break;
    default:
        die('error');
}
```

In file `my_module.js` you've got:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on('click', '#myButton', function(){
        createProduct('a_value');
    });
});

function createProduct(value) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: baseDir + 'modules/mymodule/ajax/my_module_ajax.php?rand=' + new Date().getTime(),
        headers: { "cache-control": "no-cache" },
        async: true,
        cache: false,
        data: 'action=createProduct&value=' + value+ '&other=' + 'test',
        success: function(data)
        {
            console.log("product created");
        }
    });
}
```

In file `my_module_template.tpl` you've got:

```html
<button id="myButton" name="myButton">Create product!</button>
```

This code is not tested and should be adapted to your needs but the overall concept is here.

Comment: We should add a reference to the js file into the tpl file, no ? Otherwise, the tpl file can not see our js function.

Comment: The Js file is added in the "hookHeader" function inside our module.

Comment: Ah I was putting it in `hookBackOfficeHeader` function. Other question please, have I to create different ajax files to every function I want to add ?

Comment: My bad, I wrote that code for frontOffice. But the process will be the same in backoffice, except to include the JS file. You can refer to this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/33549331/5659190

Comment: You shall keep only one file for the ajax calls or it will be a mess. Just add a little logic in it with the parameters you send from the ajax call. In the data array you can add `action=createproduct` and in the php you can add a switch on `Tools::getValue('action')`. EDIT: added it to my example

Comment: I already made another logic, adding data parameter on the function. Great answer! Thank you ! Accepted !

Comment: Other question please, how can I pass a parameter from tpl to js ? I want to send that it's a "createProduct" button to avoid making n functions for n buttons. Thanks.

Comment: Exactly, but I've tested it with `value` attribute in place of `data-action` and it's working perfectly . But I think that I'll change it to `data-action`, it's better esthetically ;)

Comment: It would be still better if you create a ModuleFrontController instead of a PHP script.