# Prestashop 1.6 addJS and andCss not work in functions module getContent() for admin

Tags: javascript, css, module, prestashop

I will add the style and javascript code to page 'configure' of new module. In function getContent() i use:

```html
  public function getContent($param){
   $output = null;

   $this->context->controller->addCSS(($this->_path).'style_module.css', 'all');
   
   return $output.$this->displayForm();
  }
```

The url to styles or javascript not show in code admin page.

How add style or js to configure module in admin in function getContent()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to add this files you need to use a hook, in this case, if you are using 1.6 version, is "actionAdminControllerSetMedia".

first you need to say that register this module in this hook in the install method of the module:

```
$this->registerHook('actionAdminControllerSetMedia');
```

The you need to specify what have to do this module in this hook, so you can use in the hook function the addCSS or addJS functions, like this:

```
public function hookActionAdminControllerSetMedia($params) { 
 $this->context->controller->addJS($this->_path.'views/js/hs_custom.js');
```

}

[Source.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33549331/8159963)

Hope it helps you.

Comment: This solution not works. Script hs_custom.js not shows on source admin page in config tab my module. Someone know why not works it?

Comment: Hi, review your code, it's working fine for me. Be sure that the path to the file is correctly, and the file exists.

Comment: It started works when i used Context::getContext->controller->addJS().
Now I using $this->context->controller->addJS and it works too.

I don't understand Prestashop :)

Comment: It's possible that existed some syntax error in your code.If the answer helped you I would be very grateful if you mark it as "Accepted answer". Thank you.