# Can't add js and css files to back office

Tags: javascript, css, prestashop-1.7, backoffice

I want to add JS and CSS files to back office in my module. But I get error: Attempted to call an undefined method named "registerStylesheet" of class "AdminModulesController".

I've seen other posts (like this [Show my module JS at footer in prestashop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31853519/show-my-module-js-at-footer-in-prestashop/53147760#53147760)) or here https://devdocs.prestashop.com/1.7/themes/getting-started/asset-management/

So I want to avoid addJS() function as this is depreciated. But when I try to use $this->context->controller->registerStylesheet() and  $this->context->controller->registerJavascript() I get the above error.

This is my whole hook code:

```
public function hookActionAdminControllerSetMedia($params)
{ 
    $this->context->controller->registerStylesheet(
        'mb_pages_content',
        'modules/'.$this->name.'/styles/admin.min.css'
    ); 

    $this->context->controller->registerJavascript(
        'mb_pages_content',
        'modules/'.$this->name.'/js/admin.js'
    );
}
```

I've checked what kind of thing is my:  $this->context->controller
but it doesn't indeed have registerStylesheet() and registerJavascript() methods. What am I missing? i do everything exactly as described everywhere in the internet, why do I get the error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**The explanation of which methods to use:**

These are `FrontController` methods in PrestaShop 1.7: `registerJavascript` and `registerStylesheet`.

These are legacy (deprecated) `FrontController` methods in PrestaShop 1.7: `addJS` and `addCSS`.

These are `AdminController` methods in PrestaShop 1.7, 1.6, 1.5: `addJS` and `addCSS`.

**So, the correct example to add a JS and a CSS files for a back-office (i.e. for AdminController) via a module class is:**

```
public function hookActionAdminControllerSetMedia($params)
{ 
    // Adds your's CSS file from a module's directory
    $this->context->controller->addCSS($this->_path . 'views/css/example.css'); 

    // Adds your's JavaScript file from a module's directory
    $this->context->controller->addJS($this->_path . 'views/js/example.js');
}
```

**For an additional information see my yet another answer [how to register JavaScript in a back-office (in admin pages)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53147760/1856214)**. I have updated it after this question.

Comment: Thank you, finally someone explained it as it supposed to be explained. But how stupid it is, that they (in Prestashop documentation) write in one sentence addJS() and addCSS() are depreciated, and in the next they explain to use them without a single note that they only remove these functions in FrontController. The other idiotic thing is, why would they leave two different methods for including files, different in FrontController and for AdminController? This is sooooo illogic, that I am scared how much more of such sh*t is waiting for me while working with prestashop...

Comment: You will find much more times as such confusing code ;) Can you please mark my answer as the best of the answers, if it is?

Comment: I was exactly in the same situation, trying to avoid addJS as I thought (based on the misleading documentation) that is was deprecated for every purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Try with :

```
$this->addJs(
     _PS_MODULE_DIR_ .'objet/views/js/feature.js',
     'all'
);
$this->addCss(
      _PS_MODULE_DIR_ .'objet/views/css/feature.css',
      'all'
);
```

Regards

Comment: This is not a solution as the Prestashop doc says: Backward compatibility is kept for the addJS(), addCSS(), addJqueryUI() and addJqueryPlugin() methods. Incidentally, now is the best time to update your libraries and use the new method.

Comment: And   $this->context->controller->addJS(($this->_path).'views/js/function.js');