# Link external JS file to Prestashop

Tags: javascript, prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I'm creating a custom module in Prestashop 1.7, and I've tried many solutions but nothing solved my problem.

I would add an external JS file to the header or footer of the website where the module is installed (and only when it's installed).

```
<script src="https://cdn.monurl.com/file.js"></script> // JS file to include
```

I tried to use the `addJS()` method in the **displayHeader** hook:

```
public function hookDisplayHeader($params)
{
    if (!$this->active)
        return;

    $this->context->controller->addJS('https://cdn.monurl.com/file.js');
}

public function install()
{
    return parent::install() && $this->registerHook('displayHeader');
}
```

I made a lot of tests, and the `hookDisplayHeader()` function is called, but my JS file doesn't appear in the `<head>` of my page.

The Prestashop documentation is limited, but after many researches, I think I can only use the `addJS()` method with internal JS files. Am I right?

How should I do to add an external JS file to my header (or footer before `</body>`)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`addJS()` function is deprecated in PrestaShop 1.7. You now have to use `registerJavascript()`.

```
    $this->context->controller->registerJavascript(
        'monurl', // Unique ID
        'https://cdn.monurl.com/file.js', // JS path
        array('server' => 'remote', 'position' => 'bottom', 'priority' => 150) // Arguments
    );
```

The important argument you must not forget here is `'server' => 'remote'` to load an external JS file.

You can find more information about this function here in the doc: https://developers.prestashop.com/themes/assets/index.html

Another think about your code, you do not have to put:

```
if (!$this->active)
    return;
```

The entire hook will not be called if the module is disabled.

Comment: Thanks! Where can I get a great documentation about Prestashop and its versions? I would like to find doc for context variable and values, but it seems to be depreciate.

Comment: Depending on what you are looking for, you can find information here http://doc.prestashop.com/  or here https://developers.prestashop.com/

Answer (score 1):

This method `addJs` is obsolete for Prestashop 1.7*. Use

```
$this->context->controller->registerJavascript('cdn', 'https://cdn.monurl.com/file.js', array('media' => 'all', 'priority' => 10, 'inline' => true, 'server' => 'remote'));
```

where first parameter is an identificator of a new script to avoid next its including if it was included once, the second parameter is a path to a media file, and the last parameter is an array with extra information about new media file where parameter 'server' point out that a file is on remote server. By the way, css files are including the same way now with the method `$this->context->controller->registerStylesheet();`

Answer (score 1):

**In PrestaShop 1.7 for a front-office page you need to use another method to add an external JS file: `registerJavascript`.** But for a back-office page you can do it as usual.

**So, for example, to add a JavaScript file to a front-office page** from the `https://ajax.googleapis.com` website you need use the new method `registerJavascript` with the option `'server' => 'remote'`:

```
$this->context->controller->registerJavascript(
    'three.js',
    'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/threejs/r84/three.min.js',
    ['position' => 'bottom', 'priority' => 100, 'server' => 'remote']
);
```

To add a CSS file you can use another new method of FrontController: `registerStylesheet`.